# When i click on refresh all , sometimes all the queries in excel does not refresh , what could be the possible cause for this ? Manually refresh works

Tags: excel, export-to-excel

In Excel, I have daily reports Refresh All, does not do the job any alternative for the same ?
Another problem is, it says Download failed, it is daily report so generally after 3 or 4 refresh, there is this Excel Error Load failed. (I tried alternative file without refresh versions and that works weird )

- I tried manually refreshing individual queries and that works fine.
- Curious because, some days the "Refresh All" in Excel does work and does the job.
- It does not work 70 percent of the time.
  -Finally, I would want to automate this process using Windows Task Scheduler(maybe Event triggered is VPN connection or Opening of an Excel file )

Comment: What's your data source that you're leveraging Refresh All?  It sounds like you may have issues with a connection that if the refreshes are happening in parallel, you're getting time outs.  You can use VBA to manage refreshes, though you may have limited success there without some built-in 'sleep' periods between refreshes.